# Can Commander's Strike allow an ally to cast a spell or use a magic item?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, battle-master

In reading through the text for Commander's Strike ...

> When you take the Attack action on your turn, you can forgo one of your attacks and use a bonus action to direct one of your companion to strike. When you do so, choose a friendly creature who can see or hear you and expend one superiority die. That creature can immediately use its reaction to make one weapon attack, adding the superiority die to the attack's damage roll.

... this part stood out to me.

> ...make one weapon attack...

I know this should seem pretty obvious but what kind of actions could my ally take?  Obviously using a mundane weapon attack is allowed but is a spellcaster allowed to cast a spell, or to use an equipped spell-like item such as a wand or spell charged item? It seems really pointless to forgo a fighter attack (who probably have the most damaging normal attacks anyway) for say... a wizard with a sling, but if they could cast a spell that seems fair.

Maybe if the wizard used the ability of a weapon (a quarterstaff with spell charges for instance) that would be an appropriate interpretation? I don't see any good tactical application for the interpretation where it is mundane weapons only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Commander's Strike only allows weapon attacks.

When you use Commander's Strike, your ally can only make a weapon attack, nothing more. In general, this will mean making a single attack with whatever weapon they are already holding. Spell attacks are not weapon attacks. Items that are not weapons do not make weapon attacks unless their descriptions say so or they are used as improvised weapons. Basically, the ally has to smash, slash, or stab someone with something else, and that's all they can do.

## Why it still has good tactical applications.

You're right that this is trading one of your attacks for one of the ally's attacks, which at first doesn't seem to be very advantageous. However, Commander's Strike has several properties that mean it's not a zero-sum trade. The following are the properties affecting the ally's attack that differ from the attack you are trading away.

1. The ally gets to add the superiority die to the attack's damage. (Most weapons deal a single die of damage, so getting to roll two dice is, to generalize substantially, a lot like rolling damage for a critical hit. This gets better as the superiority die gets larger.)
2. The ally is in a different location than you are.
3. The ally has different weapons and features than you do.

If you keep those properties in mind, the following are some scenarios that benefit from the use of Commander's Strike. It's very situational, so this is not an exhaustive list, but this should help you identify good tactical opportunities when they arise.

1. **Pressing Need.** If an attack against a particular target simply can't wait but you yourself are incapable of or unwilling to do it, Commander's Strike allows someone else to do it instead, and with greatly improved chances due to the attack roll bonus. For example:

   1. When you're too far away from the target.
   2. When there's cover, terrain, or obstacles between you and the target.
   3. When you'd provoke too many opportunity attacks on your way to the target.
2. **Optimal Alternative.** If the ally has a feature you don't have that would benefit the outcome or is otherwise a better or vital candidate for making the attack, Commander's Strike allows you to give them an extra chance to use it. For example:

   1. You give the Rogue an extra chance to use their Sneak Attack.
   2. You give a caster an extra chance to hit with the weapon created by the *shadow blade* spell (an odd case where a spell creates a wielded eapon).
   3. You give the Druid wildshaped as a dire wolf another attack with Pack Tactics now that the party has positioned themselves more tactically since the Druid's last turn.
   4. The campaign uses the optional flanking rules, you've got an Extra Attack to spare, you're now flanking the target with an ally, and you want the narrative satisfaction of taking the enemy down as a team.
   5. You give the wielder of the *sword of villain's weakness* the chance to deliver the killing blow even though they couldn't do it on their own turn.

These two categories probably cover the majority of cases when Commander's Strike is useful. I hope this sheds light on its utility.

Comment: In D&D 5e, average damage listings and half points of damage are rounded down. Since there's no such thing as a +4.5 bonus, it would be disingenuous to round up and inaccurate to not round, I think +4 is the only sensible representation.

Comment: @Bloodcinder if you are using the stat block of a creature for speed, yes. If instead you are talking about the average long term damage from rolling dice that a PC will output you shouldn’t round down (as they will, *on average* output 4.5 damage per attack)

Comment: You've written the D8 bonus as being to attack, though the OP quote says it's to damage?

Comment: @PaulHutton: I was just about to point that out myself. It's added to damage, not the attack roll.

Comment: @PaulHutton Good catch. I need to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

## A weapon attack is an attack with a weapon.

D&D is an exceptions based game. As such it uses the normal English meaning of words, unless a specific rule states otherwise.

Under the normal English meaning of the word weapon something has to be an object to be a weapon. It also has to cause damage when a creature or an object is struck with it (which can include firing ammo). In addition body parts like fists and feet can be understood to be weapons in the proper context.

As such, something is a weapon if:

1. It can be normally understood to be a weapon
2. It says in the object description it is a weapon

As such spells are not weapons (through some spells like Shadow Blade do create weapons).

Items like wands are also not weapons unless they say they are (obviously DM Fiat can always determine something to be a weapon if the DM decides it is).

Comment: Jut for clarity: [Unarmed strikes are not made with weapons, but they are still considered melee weapon attacks.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/608776737917263872) Otherwise, you are correct; weapons are items in the Weapons list in the rules, and other items can be used as improvised weapons to make weapon attacks.

Comment: @V2Blast that’s why I mentioned “in the proper context” in my answer when talking about body parts and their relationship to weapons.

Comment: @V2Blast Also the weapons list in the PHB is explicitly non-exhaustive. If something is in that list then it is a weapon. If it’s not in that list it can still be a weapon if the item/object description states that it is one.